# Creating array of arrays of objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently my data is an array with a long list of objects in the format:

```
[ 
    { name: 'example' },
    { name: 'example' },
    ...
]
```

What I am trying to do is to convert this list into arrays of arrays of objects at a given interval, 20.

I want this format:

```
[
  [
   { name: 'example' },
   { name: 'example' },
    ...18 more rows
   ],
  [
   { name: 'example' },
   { name: 'example' },
    ...18 more rows
  ],
]
```

chartdata contains the data in initial format, I am trying to get the new format in 'newArray'. In order to achieve this I have put:

```
  let newArray = [];
  let data = [];

  chartdata.forEach((x, i) => {
    if(i === chartdata.length - 1 ){
      newArray.push(data)
      data = []
    }
    if(i%20===0){
      newArray.push(data)
      data = []
    }
    data.push(x);
  })
  console.log('newArray',newArray)
```

There are two things I do not understand.

The console log shows the below:

[image]

Why is there an empty array in the first index of newArray?

- Thank you, I have added && i !== 0 in the second if statement.

Why does index 4 of newArray only have 19 values?

The first question is fairly easy to resolve, however the second question I do not understand how to fix. Please can anyone provide some help?

Comment: The first array is empty bcoz `0%20 = 0` so the 2nd condition gets true and the empty array is pushed into the final array

Comment: forEach((x,i) => {}) Here, in this line x is current element and I is its index. Indexes start from 0 in Javascript. Hence for the first element x, index i=0 & i%20 === 0 is true (as 0%20 is equal to 0) & hence empty data array which is initialized in 2nd line of code is being pushed into newarray and that is why index 0 of newarray is empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to integrating other packages into the project, I believe the function `chunk` from Lodash serves exactly this purpose: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk

The code becomes as simple as (and much clear in terms of what is happening):

```
const chunks = _.chunk(chartdata, 20);
```

In general, since it seems you will be working a lot with arrays, consider integrating Lodash into your project, the library targets exactly the many operations one would want to perform with arrays. I have been working several years with the library in my projects, and hardly ever (if ever) came across an operation that was not covered by their functions.

There are some [suggestions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark) regarding optimization, but to be honest I never found importing the whole library to be a problem when it comes to bundle size.

Answer (score 0):

```
let i,j, newArray = [],chunk = 20;
for (i=0,j=chartdata.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    newArray.push(chartdata.slice(i,i+chunk));
}
```

Comment: an explanation is often helpful